# 504 gateway time-out server didn't respond in time issue

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, apache2

I've looked throughout this site to see if I could find a solution but haven't found one.

I have a problem with a 504 gateway time-out server message that keeps popping up.
I was able to successfully setup my MySQL database to capture data from my webpage, with `dbconnect.php`, using my `localhost/index.html`.  However, when I try to access it via my Virtualbox(running windows 7/10) I keep getting a 504 gateway time-out server didn't respond in time, message.  I changed my `$host name` from `localhost` to `supporthtech.hopto.org`(I'm using NOIP).  I also increased my `max_input_time` and `max_execution_time` from 120 to 3000.  That doesn't seem to help.  On my VM, I'm using a proxy server to mimic someone from outside my network trying to login to my website.

Like I've said at the beginning.  MySQL database is able to successfully collect information when I setup my website locally(using `localhost/index.html`).
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I'm not clear, are you trying to use the phpMyAdmin application or some other code? I don't think you've mentioned any phpMyAdmin files in your explanation, but you've tagged phpmyadmin so it's not clear if this is with some other code or the phpMyAdmin application.

Comment: My apologies.  I'm talking about my dbconnect.php file. I'm using phpMyAdmin application to connect to my webpage. my webpage asks for some information and when the customer hits "send", the data is saved in mysql database. When I have my .php file setup as localhost everything works great.  But when I log into my VM and use a proxy server(to make it look like I"m not in my own network), I'm still able to access my webpage, but I get a "504 gateway timeout server didn't respond" error.  I"m just trying to figure out why that is.  I don't think it has anything to do with my dbconnect.php

Comment: Okay, now it makes more sense - but to make a minor correction, you're not using phpMyAdmin to connect this to your web page. The phpMyAdmin application is a graphical interface for administrators to maintain a MySQL or MariaDB database, and you probably use it yourself to do administrative work on the database, but it has nothing to do with your application. Your application seems to be PHP code that talks directly to MySQL without going through phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Any hints in the proxy logs?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect you to run the web server from the same host as your database is running on, so you should continue to connect from the web page to "localhost" - regardless of how your browser is connecting to the web page, the connection between the database and the web server continues to be local. So regardless of where in the world or which virtual machine you're using, your browser should connect to the web server which you're running on the same host as the database server. There's no need to change the host string for your PHP script for the database connection if you're accessing from another host, since *to the web server* the database host hasn't changed. This is one of the great things about networking, if you connect to the web server it doesn't matter what is going on behind the scenes on the network because, to the web browser, all it has to do is talk to the web server; the details under the web server can be as complex or simple as your topology requires.

That seems to be the most likely cause of your trouble, so I suggest changing the connection host back to localhost and accessing your web server itself remotely. If that causes you trouble, then there's something else wrong with your web server configuration (or ISP, or port forwarding on your router, etc) that you can ask another question about.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It really helped alot for me to understand how everything functions together.  As you stated in your previous post, I went ahead and changed my host string back to "localhost". I don't think I mentioned this in my previous posts, but I use "NOIP" and xamp(Since I use linux, its called "LAMP" I believe). I"m sure you heard about this, but the application has 3 servers running. Mysql, proftd and apache web server.On my ISP router, I used port-forward for HTTP.  I used my static ip address of my laptop(which serves as my apache/mysql db) for the "internal host".

Comment: UPDATE:  I got it to work!  I think changing the host string back to "localhost" in my db_connect.php file.  I thought I had done that before?  I remember trying every single combination for my $host string. Maybe I thought I did but in reality I didn't?  Anyways, it works now so thats the important thing.  What I did is, using NOIP, create a hostname called, "supporthtech.hotpto.org" (I linked my ISP's address to my hostname) My db_connect.php file containes my $host, $password, $username, $db_name and $tbl_name along with the proper code to add user info to mysql db.  On my VM I used

Comment: (cont'd) a free proxy server(for testing purposes) connected to my web server using my hostname(I created with NOIP) "supporthtech.hotpto.org" and filled in the proper information and it worked.  I had set my $host string to my hostname I created, but that didn't work, I then set it to my static pc ip, but that didn't work as well.  I'm pretty sure I tried using "localhost" as the $host string. In making all those changes I made sure to restart apache/mysql/proftd servers.  I'm wondering if my bandwidth was too slow? I use 5G so I'm not sure thats the issue, but maybe time of day made it slow?